# Automate start of LanmanServer on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, services

**B**ackground:

On my work machine and my colleagues' machines, the `LanmanServer` seems to always be set to startup type Disabled even when it was set by the user to Automatic. This means that the user needs to run `services` each time and run it by going through the GUI whenever a reset is needed before it resumes to work.

**Q**uestion:

Is there any way to automate the process of starting this service?

**F**ailed solutions:

`net start server`

and simply setting it to automatic, as well as editing the registry.

The goal is to *remove* this step from the workflow in order to have access to docker desktop as soon as the PC boots.

Comment: You mention work machines. Are these in a domain? If so your SysAdmin probably has disabled this service by GroupPolicy. And that is why it disables itself again and again. Talk to your SysAdmin if you can get an exception to that policy. Besides that the proper command is "net start lanmanserver" and you could put that in a Scheduled Task run on login. (Needs to run with ADMIN rights!!)

Comment: Hello @Tonny
Hi, how do you check GroupPolicy?
Would you like to describe how you would setup that task inside Task Scheduler?
I know how I'd do it but perhaps others can learn and also, perhaps the way I'd do it is not the optimal way.

Comment: I would have to lookup the details on a Windows PC which won't be possible for several days. (I'm traveling for the holidays and posting this from my phone while waiting in the airport.)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that your computer is in a domain and that the
domain administrator has decided to disable this system service.

To verify that this is indeed the case, you can list all the
policies applied to your computer that differ from Windows defaults.

For policies applying to your user account use the following command
inside a Command Prompt (cmd):

```
gpresult /Scope User /v
```

The /v parameter specifies verbose results,
so you’ll see everything. Scroll down and you’ll find the
information below the section named "Resultant Set Of Policies for User".

For all policies applied to your computer, change the scope argument:

```
gpresult /Scope Computer /v
```

The policy you're looking for might be under the
Windows Settings node > Security Settings > System Services.

If you do find such a policy,
I advise you to first contact the administrator and ask if you're
allowed to re-enable this service. Your workplace might not
appreciate you overriding company security policies.

If permitted, to override that policy, you will need to execute
the command `net start lanmanserver` after login
(requires elevation), for example using the Task Scheduler.

References :

- [How to See Which Group Policies Are Applied to Your PC and User Account](https://www.howtogeek.com/116184/how-to-see-which-group-policies-are-applied-to-your-pc-and-user-account/)
- [HOWTO: Disable Unnecessary Services and Scheduled Tasks on AD FS Servers](https://dirteam.com/sander/2019/07/04/howto-disable-unnecessary-services-and-scheduled-tasks-on-ad-fs-servers/)